Is there a Refresh Token expiration time for in a web-app in the "Verification in progress" status?
When my web-app was in the Publishing status: "Testing" my users needed to re-signup every week, due to the expiration of their refresh token.
Since I've submitted the web-app to the Verification process I'd like to understand if the 7 days expiration time for the refresh token still apply.
This is not super clear since the Publishing status is now "Production" (as you can see from the picture). And it also looks like I do not have to enable email, but users can signin without me having to allow them (even if they see a warning message).
Can someone knows better?
I could not find any information for this, plenty of information regarding the refresh token expiration error, but nothing regarding this intermediate stage when your web-app is in the Verification process.


From what I know, the Verification Status on its own doesn't affect refresh token expiration, and if the Publishing status is set to In production, it no longer expires after seven days. You may review the question How do I deal with refresh token expiring?, as it could be the answer you're looking for.
